# 'Headers' is undefined in IE11

Tags: header, undefined, internet-explorer-11

I am using angular2csv where I export the data displayed in the table to csv. I add the headers using ,

```
  export() {
    const head = ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3', 'Header4', 'Header5'];
    const exportErrors = new Angular2Csv(this.items,
      this.obj.value, { headers: (head) });
  }
```

It works fine in CHROME, but on IE11, it gives me an error saying 'ERROR ReferenceError: 'Headers' is undefined'. What is the issue here?

What is the alternative to headers in IE11.

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered this on a different (non-angular) project. I beleive the best solution is the [whatwg-fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch).

The underlying issue is that [IE does not implement the full Fetch spec](https://caniuse.com/#search=Fetch)