# Getting "Headers is undefined" in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, internet-explorer-11

I have an react app that works as expected in all browsers, except of IE11.
in console I can see this error:

[image]

and it's pointing to this line of code:

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';

**const headers = new Headers();**
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

class ApiService extends EventEmitter {
```

I had reached these posts, but it's not clear to me what kind of change should I do! Should I only install the missing pollyfills or need to change code syntax...

['Headers' is undefined in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534859/headers-is-undefined-in-ie11)

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1275068/Javascript-fetch-not-working-in-internet-explorer

## Update

After installing both:

window.fetch # https://github.com/github/fetch#read-this-first,

promise # https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill

Now I'm getting:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'values'

I used a DataTable object of react-carbon-components, and seems it's not supported as well:

```
_defineProperty(DataTable, "translationKeys", Object.values(translationKeys));
```

export { DataTable as default };

Comment: The answer there is that you need to use a [polyfill](https://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill) so IE will behave just like the normal browsers. You can follow the installation process [here](https://github.com/github/fetch#read-this-first)

Comment: See my update. thanks for the help

Comment: This is another question, so I would suggest to create a new one. Anyway, here is your polyfill for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Polyfill. And in general, when something like that happening, search the name of the feature + `polyfill`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Headers interface of the Fetch API is not supported in Internet Explorer.

Reference:

[Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers)

To make it work with IE browser you need to use polyfill. You can refer any one of the following polyfill may help you to solve the issue.

1. [Fetch headers polyfill](https://github.com/jimmywarting/fetch-headers)
2. [window.fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Comment: You not need to install both at the same time. I suggest you to use any one of them at a time and see the results. If you get same error then let us know on which line you are getting that error and try to provide the sample code for it.

Comment: I started with window.fetch, but then got an erro regarding promise... so I had to

Comment: Can you try to post the modified version of your code with polyfill which we can try to run with IE browser for producing the new error? It can help to get more idea about this new error.

Comment: Will try to create a sandbox. But as @Mosh mentioned in his comment, need to install more pollyfills